# Is British English unwelcome on ELU for some people?

Tags: discussion

This is a genuine question, asked in a spirit of enquiry. I don't want to start a row - simply to ask for people's thoughts.

**Background**

I and some other Brits on ELU have noticed that a minority of self-declared US English speakers appear not to value our variety of the language and, as a result not value our answers.

**Examples**

I was told by one user that he'd always thought Britain was some fictional place from Star-Trek.

Another said that Britain -  the nation and its language - were of rapidly diminishing importance in the world. The implication was that my answer was therefore worthless,

I can't give you the links because I flagged these remarks and they were removed. I'm sure they are still on the system somewhere.

Edit - I've received other, milder, comments that give me the same impression.

**Discussion**

I could of course justify British English to these people, e.g.

1. The English language actually originated in England and was later exported all over the world.
2. Educated Americans are often familiar with the works of Milton, Shakespeare and Dickens as well as later writers such as, for example J.K. Rowling of Harry Potter fame. All of those wrote in the language of the British Isles.
3. Many students from Europe and Asia learn British English in school in preference to American English. I don't have precise statistics but in my home city - and many others, not even counting London - we have dozens of language schools with thousands of foreign students.
4. My username clearly indicates my origins.
5. When I answer, if I am aware of a difference, I indicate to the reader that they may wish to wait for US answers as well.

**Question**

Would people care to come forward and state their true feelings about this. Would you prefer this to a be a site for American English only?

This is a genuine question and I'm hoping for honest answers.

Comment: Is there any country other than USA that teaches Americanlish?

Comment: @JohanLarsson: I doubt it. British is still the standard, isn't it? We're busy founding a new school in Amsterdam, and I don't think anyone in our group would suggest we teach children American English. The standard language certificates people get here are from Cambridge. I'm fine with American English, but British has always been preferred. Holland is generally a forerunner in the adoption of English around Europe. Perhaps things will change if the American Empire clings to its dominant position for a bit longer, but I think it's too late.

Comment: @JohanLarsson - Your comment/rhetorical question is too oblique for me! Please could you elaborate?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: I presume he means a country where schools teach children American English by default. Perhaps such countries exist, but I've never heard of any.

Comment: N.B.: The English didn't "invent" English. They simply communicated in the language of their community, and the language changed as it would. Invention implies a deliberate act, not the somewhat random progress that actually occurred.

Comment: @Cerberus in some places it just depends on the nationality of the teacher. I had to sit through English as a foreign language classes as a child and we had English, American and Australian teachers at different points.

Comment: @terdon: Right, that is possible; but what about the text books? Did they have colour or color?

Comment: Don't remember. I was usually reading a book during those classes. The perks of being a native speaker :)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: By focusing on primacy you're trying to draw attention away from the fact that invention is still a *deliberate* process. I maintain that nobody in England who helped shape the language did so as a conscious effort to construct a means of communication. Therefore, *invent* is still a poor word choice at best, and at worst may be an attempt to take credit for something for which no real credit is due.

Comment: @Robusto - In deference to your comment, I have now removed my reference to 'invention'.  I applaud the Americans for making English the lingua franca of the world through their influence in science and the media particularly. I having started using your more sensible spelling myself in some instances (e.g. I now use 'program' instead of 'programme'). However I think it is fair to point out to critics that modern English had its beginnings in England. Some of those people aren't even aware of that despite the apparent obviousness of the fact.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: I for one cherish British English, as may be noted in  comments I've made [on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204972/word-for-an-animal-that-has-been-ridden-too-much/205005#205005) and [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=18366724#18366724). Both AmE and BrE have their flaws, but that's true of any language or dialect. And as for those who would disparage either as being inferior to the other, that's just ridiculous, and I can respond to that only with [*honi soit qui mal y pense*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honi_soit_qui_mal_y_pense).

Comment: I'm vaguely aware that some questions/comments assume the primacy of American English (or rather that when you say English it is whatever is spoken in the US). But I'm also vaguely aware of similar questions/comments with respect to British English. We're all the main characters in our own movies.

Comment: Tangentially related question: I've sometimes referred to British people (both here and "in real life") as "Brits". Do British people object to being called "a Brit"? Do they find it offensive? To be clear: I do it not because it's a nickname of some kind, but because saying or typing out "British people" every time is such a mouthful. Also, in case it's relevant, I tend to think/refer to people from England as Brits but not so much Ireland, Wales, Scotland, etc. Though technically I guess they're British too?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Funny, I actually thought about addressing that very question in my earlier comment! The short answer is no, we do not. We're vaguely aware that people from other Anglophone countries sometimes use *Yank* as a derogatory reference, but for the most part is just seems quaint to us. Like "boot" or "loo" or "lorry". PS: The Union Jack in Chasly's avatar does not get under my skin, personally.

Comment: @DanBron people of _Northern_ Ireland, Wales and Scotland are most certainly Brits. They would be very offended to be called *English*, but *British* is fine unless you come across someone more nationalistic than it's ever been my misfortune to meet. There's no "technically" about it, they are British, pure and simple. The term exists precisely to act as an all-inclusive umbrella word for the peoples of the UK.

Comment: @terdon Good to know. I worried, eg, a Scotsman might object to being labeled British. Glad to hear it's an umbrella term: makes it more useful for me. In re: the shorter term *Brit*, is that ok to use? Assuming of course I employ it in good faith.

Comment: @DanBron my Scottish friends identify as _British_, yes. As for _Brit_, I haven't had any complaints and I was using it regularly during the 4 years I spent in the UK. I've also seen it used [by the BBC](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/shared/spl/hi/in_depth/brits_abroad/html/) and the British Grammys are called [The Brit Awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brit_Awards) so yeah, I think you're pretty safe.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: As I have [stated elsewhere](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/64438/2303), Yank and Yankee are not inherently negative, but it depends on who says them and how they are said.

Comment: @DanBron please note in my previous comment to the OP that I correctly spelt your name. I know for a fact that being called *Dan Brown* really rubs you up the wrong way.  So, folks now you know :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Much obliged! Wouldn't mind so much if the guy was a decent writer.  Or, you know, not an insane conspiracy theorist.

Comment: Please remove that "example". You have found someone of such staggering ignorance that they i) don't know the language of England; ii) believe Edinburgh is in England; iii) can't spell _ancestral_ ; end questions with full stops and non-questions with question marks. That's hardly someone who's likely to hang out on a site for language enthusiasts, so this can't serve as an example of anything except extreme ignorance.

Comment: My impression is that we should not give too much attention and visibility to "stupid and offensive" comments. –  Josh61 2 hours ago

Comment: @Josh61 - It's an interesting point of view. It puts me in mind of Margaret Thatcher's internationally famous  speech on 'the oxygen of publicity'. http://legalinsurrection.com/2013/04/margaret-thatcher-and-the-oxygen-of-publicity/ - On the other hand, my hope is that those people who inhabit ELU and can be thoughtless about their comments, may see this thread and be intelligent enough to reflect on their behaviour.

Comment: @terdon - Your request to remove the example seems reasonable so I have done so. However, your statement about such people not hanging about on ELU is somewhat weakened by the existence of the user who made the Star Trek comment.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK you haven't told us who it is but I very much doubt it was one of the regulars. Drive by comments don't count as "hanging out".

Comment: @terdon - Unfortunately I'm not aware of a way to roll back deleted comments. If I could, I'd go back and check.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - I would not count much on that, I think it is just to be expected ( in a statistical sense) that a few user will misbehave, for whatever reason , here as in any other site. To redeem them is sort of a waste of time. I don't think they will damage the site future growth and development in any possible way.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: alas, to be sold in the US, the Harry Potter books have been translated into American English (I have half of the books in AmE and half in BrE). Many other recent books are translated between the two countries and, I suspect, even movies. This is something I find astonishing.

Comment: Deleting my first comment that contained certain observations, I see the OP has received an unfair number of downvotes, and I don't want to be supplying any ammunition to the "enemy".

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Thanks for your support.  I have to say that I have zero respect for drive-by downvoters if they have been here for any reasonable amount of time. I did it myself when I first joined and was getting to know the system. These days I make the effort to comment first and, if there is no response, I downvote and give my reasons.  I believe that downvoting without explaining is pointless and has much in common with spitting on people from a high-rise building.

Comment: Generally speaking, some users are very touchy, many are kind, genuinely helpful and smart but there are a few who take offence (no s!)   and take themselves far too seriously. It's easy to get caught up in that. So just breathe, step back and let it die down, otherwise just flag them to the mods.

Comment: @Mari-LouA and chasly, please remember that votes on meta are very different. First of all, they carry no reputation penalty and, secondly, are used to i) express disagreement and ii) declare a question not useful. Explaining downvotes on meta really doesn't make much sense. The people who downvoted either don't see any point to this question ("this question is not useful") or are using their downvotes as an answer: "no, BrE is not unwelcome here".

Comment: @terdon - Thanks for the info. Incidentally I notice that two people have voted to close on the grounds that my question is unclear. I don't think it could be any clearer.

Answer (score 17):

As you yourself point out, the offending comments were removed when you flagged them. Your question, therefore, reads like "Some unpleasant people acted like idiots and the mods stepped in and put things right". I don't see how you go from a couple of idiots to "ELU doesn't like BrE".

That said, remember that at least three of our mods are actually British. As are quite a few of our top-rep members. We also have 1043 questions tagged with [british-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/british-english).

So, no, of course BrE is not unwelcome here. Quite the contrary.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and reassurance. I appreciate it. However at no point did I make the generalisation that you are imputing to me.  I very carefully formulated my question to ask if a *minority* of people thought us unwelcome. I am genuinely hoping that such people will make themselves known and justify their position. Maybe it is a forlorn hope.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK you can't be expecting bigots and idiots to come out and say so. This is not the official stance of the community nor is it the stance of the majority. I've seen idiotic comments impugning upon both British and American English and in about the same amounts. There's not much else to be said.

Comment: I'll admit to a hidden agenda.  Some people don't learn and do this repeatedly. In future I plan to direct such people here and ask them to contribute their opinion.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK may I suggest you just ignore them instead? We're talking about a tiny minority who, by definition, are very unlikely to be open to argument. Just flag and move on.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - It seems a disrespectful use of meta to post a question with the intention of using it for your personal reference to the occasional slight. If everyone did this for every encountered slight, meta would be poor reading indeed.

Comment: @medica - The hidden agenda I referred to was an afterthought.  I'm afraid that I go through life like that, starting with a simple idea and then elaborating - sometimes indefinitely.  I had no intention of using this question as a personal noticeboard. Rather, as I said, the idea was simply to point people in this direction and invite them to read and/or comment. If they do comment and that makes for dull reading then so be it. I imagine, as terdon has said, that such people are unlikely to contribute. As far as I know simply reading a question doesn't bring it to the top of the queue. (?)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - My comment was, "If everyone did this for every encountered slight, meta would be poor reading indeed." I agree with most of the others here: walk away. Disengage. Ignore them. Forget it. Do we really need meta reference questions for our personal peeves?

Comment: @medica - If it was just about me then I'd agree with you. However, it's a wider issue. As I said earlier, I'm aware of others who have noticed the effect. Compared with prejudice about gender or race, it's an insignificant matter, but on this site I am part of a minority and I'm proud of my language heritage. I prefer to tackle an issue rather than simply to  'forget it'.  Now that I've posed the question and received positive and encouraging answers, I feel greatly reassured. I hope that the same will be true for other people who use different varieties of English if they happen to find this

Answer (score 7):

Just put it out of your mind. Their perspectives will gradually adjust.

Some Americans confuse xenophobia for patriotism (which is supposedly healthy), as do nationals of many countries, especially folks with more idealism than real-life experience. Chauvinism is always difficult to defuse constructively, to be sure, but however you prefer to approach that general sort of behavior should be appropriate. Flag and move along.